# Change fig size

Tags: matplotlib

How do I zoom out my fig? I'm supposed to have a disk fig, but when I changed the xlim & ylim, the fig got zoomed in.
Thanks

[image: 1]

```
 r,p = np.meshgrid(ff.x,ff.y,sparse=True)

    ...: ux=ff.uu[0,...]
    ...: uy=ff.uu[1,...]
    ...:
    ...: rho=ff.rho
    ...:
    ...: plt.contourf(x,y,np.log(rho),50,cmap='viridis') #'Spectral'
    ...: cb=plt.colorbar()
    ...: cb.set_label('Log Gas Density')
    ...: plt.ylabel('AU/1e5')
    ...: plt.xlabel('AU/1e5')
    ...: plt.xlim([-3,3])
    ...: plt.ylim([-3,3])
    ...: plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,3)
    ...: plt.title("Density")
    ...: plt.show()
```

Comment: You can just remove `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()` because `plt.contourf(...)` automatically zooms to include the full plot.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need the limit of the plot to be from (-3,3) for both the X & Y axes.

Comment: Well, either you want to zoom out, or you don't.